# Bind array param in raw query with WHERE IN/WHERE NOT IN

Tags: laravel, laravel-query-builder, laravel-10

How can I properly bind an array for a raw query's `NOT IN` / `IN`?

The following throws an array to string conversion error:

```
    $user_list_to_exclude = [1, 2, 3];
    
    $data = DB::select("SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_id NOT IN :user_list_to_exclude",
                ['user_list_to_exclude' => $user_list_to_exclude]);
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to bind parameters to a raw DB query in Laravel that's used on a model?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20864872/how-to-bind-parameters-to-a-raw-db-query-in-laravel-thats-used-on-a-model)

Comment: also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41913973/binding-parameter-to-dbraw-laravel-query

Comment: My bindings are working but not for an array. The other posts use a single value bindings (Which work for me)